# Omnichannel routing - not working as expected

Tags: case, queue, omnichannel

We are experimenting with omni-channel in a sandbox and have the following set-up:

- A service Channel which is set to only include Cases
- A single routing configuration which has priority 1 and a single queue assigned to it (of which I am a member).
- A busy presence status and an active presence status which is connected with the service channel above

However, I can't seem to get the routing to do anything we would expect:

Cases from the above queue don't seem to route to me when I log-in to Omni-channel. However, I did get a case routed to me today which I already own.

I've experimented today with manually changing the owner of cases in our sandbox to the above queue and nothing seems to happen, either.

What triggers the routing, if not the addition of the case to the queue?

We've got Omni-channel supervisor switched on and nothing seems to be happening in there when I add Cases to the queue either.

Have I misunderstood how Omni-channel is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have been the result of a few things:

- In my attempt to debug what was happening, I had multiple tabs and browsers open with Omni-channel in them. It seemede that the Omni-channel session was being disrupted
- Some of these items had previously been routed to me and declined, which may mean they weren't being re-routed to me
- We were using Workflow field updates to move the Cases into the omnichannel queue. It seems that "Order of Execution" means that these cases are not picked up by omnichannel. When we moved from Workflows to Process builder, this seemed to resolve this issue.
- We had not realised that cases routed by Omni-channel have the owner of the case automatically updated to the user, even before they've accepted it. We had thought the owner was updated when they accept it. As a result it looked to us like it was routing cases that we already owned.

We can't be sure exactly which of these  was causing the confusion, but it was likely a combination of the above and wanted to leave this here in case it is of use to others.